# I need help only printing certain lines from a textfile (perl)

Tags: perl

I've been looking around quite a while now for an answer but since I'm very new to perl I could use some help that explains my problem, as I can't take answers from other threads and tweak their codes.

The closest I got to finding the closest I was to finding a solution was:
[How can I write only certain lines of a file in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314771/how-can-i-write-only-certain-lines-of-a-file-in-perl)

It's the same problem, but I only want to write lines that start with a "/", is this possible, and if possible, how do I do it?

Any help is very appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple implementation may look like:

```
while (<>) {
    print $_ if /^\//;
}
```

This looks for a `/` immediately after the start of the line (`^`).

If you want to allow some whitespace at the start of the lines, change your regular expression to `/^[[:space:]]*\//`.

Essentially the rest of the script is the same as in the question to which you have linked.

Answer (score 2):

Perl can be used from the command-line as well for this purpose:

```
$ perl -lne 'print if /^\//' input.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fhi, '<', $input or die "Can not open file $input: $!";
while (<$fhi>) {
    print $_ if m/^\//;
}
```